# What are differences between an instruction set architecture (ISA), and a machine language?

Tags: cpu

What are differences between an instruction set architecture (ISA), and a machine language? Are they the same concept, the language in which a code can run directly on a computer? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382130/are-instruction-set-and-assembly-language-the-same-thing

Answer (score 3):

*Machine language* is the actual binary stream a CPU executes.

*Assembly language* uses mnemonics and standard syntax which is easier for people to work with.  An assembler will take a text file consisting of such and translate, or *assemble* it, into a binary *object file* containing machine language.

There may be an intermediate step called *linking* if you have code in multiple files and have instructions "calling" routines in other files.  Advanced assemblers aren't too different from compilers.

An *instruction set architecture* is a CPU manufacturer's particular definition or implementation of machine language + the mnenonics and standard syntax for it.

Most ISAs have been around a long time so there are typically many revisions.  So you have an Intel x86 ISA, but various revisions depending on whether you are talking about an old 8086, a 80286, 80386, etc.  Same thing with ARM, you have ARMv5, ARMv6, ARMv7, etc.

Comment: Does assembly language == machine language?  I thought there were sublte differences? Such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253272/whats-the-relationship-between-assembly-language-and-machine-language (although I admit I'm being pick and for the purpose of answer the question, it doesn't matter really, +1)

Comment: Generally each instruction in an assembly language will directly map to a specific "opcode", or binary value.  The assembly language is just a convenient text format for it, so you can write something easier to remember than the binary or hex equivalent.  Check out http://www.mlsite.net/8086/

Comment: Thank you for this, and the link (I wasn't trying to be difficult, I am genuinely interested :) ).

Comment: Thanks. (1)  If I understand you correctly, an ISA is the set of instructions in a machine language. Are the instructions in an ISA binary sequences?

Comment: (2) Why did I see the instructions in an ISA are human-readable words in books? Are the human-readable words that represent the instructions in an ISA the same as the mnemonics used in the assembly language of the ISA? Are the human-readable words of the instructions in an ISA part of the ISA? If yes, is there a translation process that translate from the human readable instructions in an ISA to a machine language, just like an assembler translates an assembly language to a machine language?

Comment: ISA might encompass a bit more than assembly language per se, for example things like defining the behavior of registers, quirks with instructions not necessarily obvious from mnemonic, how interrupts are handled, etc.  Not sure there is too much real difference between the terms ISA and assembly.